# Git not working after installation using ruby gem from windows

Tags: ruby, git, github, rubygems

I am installing git in my pc. I decided to use ruby gems since this is my package manager i use for most of my tools like sass and compass.

I did not encounter issue installing sass and compass and other tools. But in git i am confused since installation is pretty the same.

here what i do.

->gem install git

successfully installed!
i list all my gems and look for git using

-> gem list

I found git <1.2.7>
now i try to run basic git command such as

-> git --version
it say's
'git' is not recognize!

I just follow instruction from https://rubygems.org/gems/git
anyone installed git in windows using rubygems? I know i can install git without rubygems in my PC, but i want to stick on using ruby for now.

Thanks experts in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git` gem is not a command-line Git client, it's a library for accessing Git repositories in Ruby programs. There is no Ruby gem that will install a Git client for you. The best way to install Git on Windows is to use the Windows installer: http://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: do i need to uninstall git from gem first? May you please clarify me what was the git i was successfully installed using: -> gem install git

Comment: You don't need to uninstall it, but you might as well since you're not using it. The "git" you installed is, like I said, [a library for accessing Git repositories in Ruby programs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/git). That is to say if you're writing a program and you need the program to be able to read or modify a git repository, the gem supplies objects and methods you can use within the program to do that..

Comment: Thanks for clarification and for the link.